# How does AWS Elastic Beanstalk fulfil characteristics of cloud computing

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I am quite new to cloud computing. I've learned that AWS Elastic Beanstalk takes care of everything in background for the user, but how does it do it exacly ?

Suppose I've deployed a backend written node.js, and I have database that AWS RDS connected with the app

How are those services(AWS EB & AWS RDS) fulfil "On-demand self-service, Resource pooling, Rapid elasticity and Measured service" characteristics in practise ?

Comment: Did you try to create anything in EB?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/